# I seen many illegal site comfortable with google adsense

Tags: google-adsense

I found many sites serving Google ads that contain pornography and possible copyright infringements.

How did these sites obtain a Google AdSense ID and why does Google permit this?

Comment: There should be some reason behind negative vote. At least we can care about other questions.

Comment: I've edited your post, hopefully I've conveyed your question in a way that won't encourage down votes. @everyoneelse, 2/3 of the world does not speak English as a first language.

Comment: If you've ever uploaded some copyrighted material like a video with a soundtrack from a record to Youtube, you might know from the email you receive shortly after uploading it that Google is actually aware that a lot of the stuff on one of their sites infringes copyright, and yet they serve adverts on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get rid of these sites, then go here: https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=18386 (I've submitted a few before that were advertising porn under search terms popular with children)

If you want to do this yourself, then I doubt you'll find what you're looking for here.

Answer (score 2):

If you are registered with the AdSense program once, you can put your ads on any site you whish. It's up to you to obey the rules.

Comment: Yeah that's kind of a loophole - sign up with a "nice site" so Google will approve your application, then slap the ads code on as many sites as you like.  I think they even say that you CAN do that (use on many sites) in the terms of use, if I remember correctly (been a few years...)

Comment: they must look for domain. So no one can use it on others site using some malicious code.

Comment: I've used it on two different sites.

Comment: I use the same adsense account on many sites and it's well within the TOS. However, do note that they check all sites occasionally so if a secondary site had illegal content Google would block ads to that domain or ban you completely.

Answer (score 1):

Are you absolutely google are serving the ads? Just because it looks like a google ad doesn't mean it is a google ad.

Comment: ya definetly i confirmed brfore asking